# I have a problem with updating the product quantity

Tags: php, mysql, cart, shopping-cart, product-quantity

I have a problem in updating the quantity of the product
when I press the button 'plus', the quantity is not updated

```
<i class="fas fa-plus plus " id="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" ></i>  
<input type="text"   value="<?php echo $product_quantity ?>"      id="quantity3<?php echo $product_id ?>"/>  
<i class="fas fa-minus minus" id="<?php echo $product_id; ?>"  ></i>    
    

<script>
$(document).on('click', '.plus', function(){    
       $.ajax({
          method:"POST",
          data:{ 
                 action:"plus" ,   
                 product_id: $(this).attr("id"),    
                 ip:$('#ip1'+$(this).attr("id")).val(),     
                 product_imgsrira:$('#imgsrira1'+$(this).attr("id")).val(),     
                 product_title:$('#title1'+$(this).attr("id")).val(),       
                 product_prix:$('#prix1'+$(this).attr("id")).val(),           
                 product_quantity: $(this).parent().find('#quantity3'+$(this).attr("id")).val(   parseInt($(this).parent().find('#quantity3'+$(this).attr("id")).val()) + 1  ) 
               },      
         success:function()  {  ajaxx();  alert("Item update");  }
 
        });     
});
        
</script>



<?php
if($_POST['action'] == "plus")
    {   
        foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
        {
            if($values["product_id"] == $_POST["product_id"])
            {
             $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys] = array  (  'ip' => get_ip(),  'product_id' => $_POST["product_id"],    'product_imgsrira' => $_POST["product_imgsrira"],    'product_title' => $_POST["product_title"],              'product_prix' => $_POST["product_prix"],   'product_quantity' => $_POST["product_quantity"]          );
 
            }
         }
    }      
?>
```

I have a problem in updating the quantity of the product
when I press the button 'plus', the quantity is not updated

Comment: `action:"updatephp"` but comparing `$_POST['action']` with `plus`.

Comment: I changed it But that is not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem
I just moved the code from Ajax

```
$(this).parent().find('#quantity3'+$(this).attr("id")).val(   parseInt($(this).parent().find('#quantity3'+$(this).attr("id")).val()) + 1  );
```

I added this code in Ajax

```
product_quantity: $('#quantity3'+$(this).attr("id")).val(),
```

And the final code looks like this

```
<i class="fas fa-plus plus " id="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" ></i>  
<input type="text"   value="<?php echo $product_quantity ?>"      id="quantity3<?php echo $product_id ?>"/>  
<i class="fas fa-minus minus" id="<?php echo $product_id; ?>"  ></i>    
    

<script>
$(document).on('click', '.plus', function(){

$(this).parent().find('#quantity3'+$(this).attr("id")).val(   parseInt($(this).parent().find('#quantity3'+$(this).attr("id")).val()) + 1  ); 
    
       $.ajax({
          method:"POST",
          data:{ 
                 action:"plus" ,   
                 product_id: $(this).attr("id"),    
                 ip:$('#ip1'+$(this).attr("id")).val(),     
                 product_imgsrira:$('#imgsrira1'+$(this).attr("id")).val(),     
                 product_title:$('#title1'+$(this).attr("id")).val(),       
                 product_prix:$('#prix1'+$(this).attr("id")).val(),           
                 product_quantity: $('#quantity3'+$(this).attr("id")).val(), 
               },      
         success:function()  {  ajaxx();  alert("Item update");  }
 
        });     
});
        
</script>



<?php
if($_POST['action'] == "plus")
    {   
        foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
        {
            if($values["product_id"] == $_POST["product_id"])
            {
             $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys] = array  (  'ip' => get_ip(),  'product_id' => $_POST["product_id"],    'product_imgsrira' => $_POST["product_imgsrira"],    'product_title' => $_POST["product_title"],              'product_prix' => $_POST["product_prix"],   'product_quantity' => $_POST["product_quantity"]          );
 
            }
         }
    }      
?>
```